# Undefined Variable :value in _form in yii2

Tags: yii2

I need to add a textfield which does not belong to the model.
So I've added the following code in the form

```
<?= Html::textInput("totaldays", $value) ?>
```

Please tell me how to declare this variable or how can I resolve this.
I've tried adding

```
public $value;
```

in the model. But the error remains. Please help.

Controller

```
public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            'totaldays' => $value,
        ]);
    }
```

view.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\modules\salary\models\Salary */
//@var $model yii\base\Model
//@var $totaldays any

$this->title = $model->s_id;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Salaries', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="salary-view">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Update', ['update', 'id' => $model->s_id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?= Html::a('Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $model->s_id], [
            'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
            'data' => [
                'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?',
                'method' => 'post',
            ],
        ]) ?>
    </p>

    <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            's_id',
            's_date',
            's_period',
            's_empid',
            's_empname',
            's_workingdays',
            's_leave',
            's_holiday',
            's_wageperday',
            's_totalwage',
            's_ovthour',
            's_ovtrateperhour',
            's_ovtamount',
            's_tiffinworkingday',
            's_tiffinrateperday',
            's_wdtiffinamount',
            's_sundayworked',
            's_sundayrate',
            's_sundaytiffinamount',
            's_nightcount',
            's_nightallrate',
            's_nightallowance',
            's_convday',
            's_convrate',
            's_conveyanceamount',
            's_tiffinovtcount',
            's_tiffinovtrate',
            's_tiffinovtamount',
            's_incentivecount',
            's_incentiverate',
            's_incentive',
            's_totalearning',
            's_epf',
            's_esi',
            's_ptax',
            's_takehome',
        ],
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

_form.php

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
                <?= Html::textInput("totaldays", $value) ?>
                </div>
```

error -

```
Undefined variable: value
```

Comment: can you tell exactly how you are using `_form.php. I can not find in you upper code use or include of this file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Contoller Code should like : -

```
public function actionCreate()
{
  ......your rest of code.........

  $value = 'my Value';
  return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'value' => $value
        ]);
}

public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    ......your rest of code.........

  $value = 'my Value';
  return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'value' => $value
        ]);
}
```

Then in `create.php` and `update.php`
Change :-

```
<?= $this->render('_form', [
    'model' => $model,
    'value' => $value
]) ?>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115476/discussion-between-tanmay-and-double-h).